# How to reshape data.frames in a list?

Tags: r, reshape, transpose, reshape2

I have a list like this

```
A <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2), b = c(3, 4))
B <- data.frame(c = c(1, 2), d = c(3, 4))
g <- list(var1 = A, var2 = B)
```

producing

```
> g
$var1
  a b
1 1 3
2 2 4

$var2
  c d
1 1 3
2 2 4
```

Now I want to transpose list elements like this

```
lapply(g, function(x) data.frame(t(x)))
```

but this produces a, b, c d, as rownames which is not what I want

```
> lapply(g, function(x) data.frame(t(x)))
$var1
  X1 X2
a  1  2
b  3  4

$var2
  X1 X2
c  1  2
d  3  4
```

I would like to generete a new column into these data.frames for a, b, c, and d. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point 1: if you are transposing data, it most likely means you should use arrays, not data.frames.

However, if this **really** is what you want to do, then simply `cbind()` in the column names:

```
lapply(g, function(x) as.data.frame(cbind(colnames(x), t(x))))
$var1
  V1 V2 V3
a  a  1  2
b  b  3  4

$var2
  V1 V2 V3
c  c  1  2
d  d  3  4
```